# Insert textboxes into a .xaml.cs code and execute, creating a SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, xaml

I have the following .xaml.cs code and I have written an interface with .xaml. Unfortunately, everything does not work as it should. My interface has 3 free text boxes. After the button pressing the ExecuteSQLButton_Click function, these three text boxes should insert the text boxes into the placeholders in the code and then execute the code. The code should create a table in my SQL database. Unfortunately an error incorrect syntax near '}' happens.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Below you can see the .xaml.cs and the .xaml code. Or does anyone have an idea how to make the function work so that what I have described happens? The database names are anonymized.

.xaml.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace TimeSheetManagement_App_02
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private const int modeColumnIndex = 6;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InsertContentButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string folderPath = "folderpath";
            string serverName = "serverName";
            string databaseName = "databaseName";

            ProcessExcelFiles(folderPath, serverName, databaseName);

            MessageBox.Show("Der Inhalt wurde eingefügt.");
        }

        private void ProcessExcelFiles(string folderPath, string serverName, string databaseName)
        {
            string[] excelFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xlsx");

            string connectionString = $"Data Source={serverName};Initial Catalog={databaseName};Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

            CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                Parallel.ForEach(excelFiles, excelFile =>
                {
                    using (XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(excelFile))
                    {
                        IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(1);

                        string personalNumberExcel = worksheet.Cell("E3").Value.ToString();
                        int yearExcel;
                        if (int.TryParse(worksheet.Cell("E6").Value.ToString(), out yearExcel))
                        {
                            int startRow = 9;
                            int endRow = 38;

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet.Cell("A39").Value.ToString()))
                            {
                                endRow = 39;
                            }

                            for (int row = startRow; row <= endRow; row++)
                            {
                                string dateValueExcel = worksheet.Cell(row, 1).Value.ToString().Trim();

                                DateTime dateValue;
                                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValueExcel, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
                                {
                                    string startTimeString = worksheet.Cell(row, 3).Value.ToString().Trim();
                                    string endTimeString = worksheet.Cell(row, 4).Value.ToString().Trim();
                                    string modeValue = worksheet.Cell(row, modeColumnIndex).Value.ToString().Trim();

                                    DateTime? startTime = ParseTime(startTimeString, culture);
                                    DateTime? endTime = ParseTime(endTimeString, culture);

                                    string tableName = FindTableName(connection, personalNumberExcel, yearExcel);

                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName))
                                    {
                                        InsertDataIntoTable(connection, tableName, dateValue, startTime, endTime, modeValue);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Entsprechende Tabelle nicht gefunden.");
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Ungültiges Datumsformat in Zeile {row}: {dateValueExcel}");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Ungültiges Jahr in Zelle E6: {worksheet.Cell("E6").Value}");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        private string FindTableName(SqlConnection connection, string personalNumber, int year)
        {
            string query = "SELECT t.TABLE_NAME " +
                           "FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t " +
                           "JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1 ON t.TABLE_NAME = c1.TABLE_NAME " +
                           "JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2 ON t.TABLE_NAME = c2.TABLE_NAME " +
                           "WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' " +
                           "AND c1.COLUMN_NAME = 'Year' " +
                           "AND c2.COLUMN_NAME = 'Personalnumber' " +
                           "AND c1.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' " +
                           "AND c2.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' " +
                           "AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' " +
                           "AND c1.TABLE_CATALOG = @DatabaseName " +
                           "AND c2.TABLE_CATALOG = @DatabaseName " +
                           "AND t.TABLE_CATALOG = @DatabaseName " +
                           "AND c1.DATA_TYPE = 'int' " +
                           "AND c2.DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar' " +
                           "AND c1.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NULL " +
                           "AND c2.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 50 " +
                           "AND t.TABLE_NAME IN " +
                           "( " +
                           "    SELECT c1.TABLE_NAME " +
                           "    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1 " +
                           "    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2 ON c1.TABLE_NAME = c2.TABLE_NAME " +
                           "    WHERE c1.COLUMN_NAME = 'Year' " +
                           "    AND c2.COLUMN_NAME = 'Personalnumber' " +
                           "    AND c1.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' " +
                           "    AND c2.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' " +
                           "    AND c1.TABLE_CATALOG = @DatabaseName " +
                           "    AND c2.TABLE_CATALOG = @DatabaseName " +
                           "    AND c1.DATA_TYPE = 'int' " +
                           "    AND c2.DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar' " +
                           "    AND c1.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NULL " +
                           "    AND c2.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 50 " +
                           ")";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatabaseName", connection.Database);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string tableName = reader["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                        if (CheckMatchingValues(connection, tableName, personalNumber, year))
                        {
                            reader.Close();
                            return tableName;
                        }
                    }

                    reader.Close(); // Close the SqlDataReader after reading data
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        private bool CheckMatchingValues(SqlConnection connection, string tableName, string personalNumber, int year)
        {
            string query = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [{tableName}] WHERE Year = @Year AND Personalnumber = @PersonalNumber";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", year);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalNumber", personalNumber);

                int count = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

                return count > 0;
            }
        }

        private void InsertDataIntoTable(SqlConnection connection, string tableName, DateTime date, DateTime? startTime, DateTime? endTime, string modeValue)
        {
            string query = $"UPDATE [{tableName}] SET Starttime = @StartTime, Endtime = @EndTime, ModeofOperation = @ModeValue WHERE [Date] = @Date";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartTime", startTime != null ? startTime.Value.TimeOfDay : TimeSpan.Zero);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndTime", endTime != null ? endTime.Value.TimeOfDay : TimeSpan.Zero);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModeValue", modeValue);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        private DateTime? ParseTime(string timeString, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeString))
            {
                return null;
            }

            DateTime time;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(timeString, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out time))
            {
                return time;
            }

            return null;
        }


        private void ExecuteSQLButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=databaseName Security=true;";

            string sql = "databaseName\n" +
                         "-- Erstelle die Tabelle, falls sie noch nicht existiert\n" +
                         "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = '" + myTextBox.Text + "')\n" +
                         "BEGIN\n" +
                         "    CREATE TABLE " + myTextBox.Text + "(\n" +
                         "        Date DATE PRIMARY KEY,\n" +
                         "        Weekday NVARCHAR(20),\n" +
                         "        Year INT,\n" +
                         "        Month INT,\n" +
                         "        Day INT,\n" +
                         "        Holiday NVARCHAR(50),\n" +
                         "        Personalnumber NVARCHAR(50),\n" +
                         "        Team NVARCHAR(50),\n" +
                         "        FulltimeParttime NVARCHAR(50),\n" +
                         "        ModeofOperation NVARCHAR(50),\n" +
                         "        StartTime TIME,\n" +
                         "        EndTime TIME\n" +
                         "    );\n" +
                         "END\n" +
                         "\n" +
                         "DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '" + myTextBox3.Text + "-01-01'\n" +
                         "DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '" + myTextBox3.Text + "-12-31'\n" +
                         "\n" +
                         "WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate\n" +
                         "BEGIN\n" +
                         "    DECLARE @Holiday NVARCHAR(50) = NULL\n" +
                         "    DECLARE @Easter DATETIME\n" +
                         "    DECLARE @EasterDay INT\n" +
                         "    DECLARE @EasterMonth INT\n" +
                         "\n" +
                         "    IF MONTH(@StartDate) = 1 AND DAY(@StartDate) = 1\n" +
                         "        SET @Holiday = 'NewYear'\n" +
                         "    ELSE IF MONTH(@StartDate) = 1 AND DAY(@StartDate) = 6\n" +
                         "        SET @Holiday = 'Święto Trzech Króli'\n" +
                         "    ELSE IF MONTH(@StartDate) = 5 AND DAY(@StartDate) = 1\n" +
                         "        SET @Holiday = 'Święto Państwowe'\n" +
                         "    ELSE IF MONTH(@StartDate) = 5 AND DAY(@StartDate) = 3\n" +
                         "        SET @Holiday = 'Święto Narodowe Trzeciego Maja'\n" +
                         "    ELSE IF MONTH(@StartDate) = 6 AND DAY(@StartDate) = 8\n" +
                         "        SET @Holiday = 'Dzień Bożego Ciała'\n" +
                         "    ELSE IF MONTH(@StartDate) = 8 AND DAY(@StartDate) = 15\n" +
                         "        SET @Holiday = 'Wniebowzięcie Najświętszej Maryi Panny'\n" +
                         "    ELSE IF MONTH(@StartDate) = 11 AND DAY(@StartDate) = 1\n" +
                         "        SET @Holiday = 'Wszystkich Świętych'\n" +
                         "    ELSE IF MONTH(@StartDate) = 12 AND DAY(@StartDate) = 25\n" +
                         "        SET @Holiday = 'Pierwszy dzień Bożego Narodzenia'\n" +
                         "    ELSE IF MONTH(@StartDate) = 12 AND DAY(@StartDate) = 26\n" +
                         "        SET @Holiday = 'Drugi dzień Bożego Narodzenia'\n" +
                         "    ELSE\n" +
                         "    BEGIN\n" +
                         "        DECLARE @Jahr INT = YEAR(@StartDate)\n" +
                         "\n" +
                         "        IF @Jahr >= 1900 AND @Jahr <= 2099\n" +
                         "        BEGIN\n" +
                         "            SET @Easter = DATEADD(DAY, \n" +
                         "                (56 - 46 * (YEAR(@StartDate) / 100) + 46 * (YEAR(@StartDate) / 400) + \n" +
                         "                ((YEAR(@StartDate) * 5) - ((YEAR(@StartDate) / 100) * 4) - 6) / 4) % 7, \n" +
                         "                CAST(@Jahr AS VARCHAR) + '-03-21')\n" +
                         "\n" +
                         "            SET @EasterDay = DAY(@Easter)\n" +
                         "            SET @EasterMonth = MONTH(@Easter)\n" +
                         "\n" +
                         "            IF MONTH(@StartDate) = @EasterMonth AND DAY(@StartDate) = @EasterDay\n" +
                         "                SET @Holiday = 'Pierwszy dzień Wielkanocy'\n" +
                         "            ELSE IF MONTH(@StartDate) = @EasterMonth AND DAY(@StartDate) = @EasterDay + 1\n" +
                         "                SET @Holiday = 'Drugi dzień Wielkanocy'\n" +
                         "            ELSE IF MONTH(@StartDate) = 5 AND DAY(DATEADD(DAY, 39, @Easter)) = DAY(@StartDate)\n" +
                         "                SET @Holiday = 'Dzien Bozego Ciala'\n" +
                         "            ELSE\n" +
                         "            BEGIN\n" +
                         "                DECLARE @Pfingsten DATETIME\n" +
                         "                SET @Pfingsten = DATEADD(DAY, 49, @Easter)\n" +
                         "\n" +
                         "                IF MONTH(@StartDate) = MONTH(@Pfingsten) AND DAY(@StartDate) = DAY(@Pfingsten)\n" +
                         "                    SET @Holiday = 'Pierwszy dzień Zielonych Świątek'\n" +
                         "            END\n" +
                         "        END\n" +
                         "    END\n" +
                         "    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM " + myTextBox.Text + " WHERE Date = @StartDate)\n" +
                         "    BEGIN\n" +
                         "        INSERT INTO " + myTextBox.Text + " (Date, Weekday, Year, Month, Day, Holiday, Personalnumber, Team, FulltimeParttime, ModeofOperation, StartTime, EndTime)\n" +
                         "        VALUES (\n" +
                         "            @StartDate,\n" +
                         "            DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @StartDate),\n" +
                         "            YEAR(@StartDate),\n" +
                         "            MONTH(@StartDate),\n" +
                         "            DAY(@StartDate),\n" +
                         "            @Holiday,\n" +
                         "            '" + myTextBox2.Text + "',\n" +
                         "            NULL,\n" +
                         "            'F',\n" +
                         "            NULL,\n" +
                         "            NULL,\n" +
                         "            NULL\n" +
                         "        )\n" +
                         "    END\n" +
                         "\n" +
                         "    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate)\n" +
                         "}\n";

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("SQL query executed successfully.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="TimeSheetManagement_App_02.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimeSheetManagement_App_02"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA21BC6" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="61" Margin="681,352,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="84"/>
        <Button Content="Insert Content" Click="InsertContentButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="113">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF2738EB" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Annual final report" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="203,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF2738EB" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Margin="484,217,16,177" Width="300" Background="#FFE7BAEE" RenderTransformOrigin="0.494,0.689" />
        <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox2" Margin="484,262,16,131" Width="300" Background="#FFE7BAEE" />
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Add new emplyee table" FontSize="14" Foreground="white" Margin="481,175,19,197" Width="300"/>
        <Button Content="Add" Click="ExecuteSQLButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="484,352,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF2738EB" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Table Name" FontSize="14" Foreground="white" Margin="340,217,360,179" Width="100"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Personnelnumber" FontSize="14" Foreground="white" Margin="340,266,336,120"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="SQL Timesheet" FontSize="14" Foreground="white" Margin="68,106,571,289" RenderTransformOrigin="0.512,0.781"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox3" Margin="484,309,16,82" Width="300" Background="#FFE7BAEE" RenderTransformOrigin="0.515,-0.901" />
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Year" FontSize="14" Foreground="white" Margin="340,312,360,82" Width="100"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TimeSheetManagement Tool" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FFEB74CB" Margin="59,30,341,361" Width="400" RenderTransformOrigin="0.512,0.781"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: See the last line of your SQL: `"}\n";`. This is the `}` it complains about. It does not have a matching `{`. Check if you need it and if so where you should put the opening bracket.